# How to get userID using javascript in a button

Tags: javascript, button

Here i am trying to get the userid if i get userid, i've to check if that userid is present in an public group and perform some function. but it's showing some error. can anyone please help me out.

```
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}}";
var user = sforce.connection.getUserInfo();
alert(user);
```

Error that i am getting.
[image]

Comment: try `{!$user.Id}`

Comment: ya i got the user id, one more thing how i can check whether userid is present in an public group @Tushar Sharma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{!$User.Id}` to directly get the current user id using global variable.

After that you can perform your next operations.

For your current case try to refresh the page and then try it again. sometimes when we don't refresh the window for long time then session.Id is expired. may be that the case.

### Updates

```
List<GroupMember> lstgroupmember = [Select UserOrGroupId, Group.Type, GroupId 
                                      From GroupMember g 
                                     where Group.type = 'Regular' 
                                       AND UserOrGroupId='YourUserID' LIMIT 1]; 
if(lstgroupmember.size()>0){ 
        //fun 
}else{ 
     // keep quiet 
}
```

Comment: ya i got the user id, one more thing how i can check whether userid is present in an public group using javascript @Tushar Sharma

Comment: @RAT__ is this chatter group or normal group?

Comment: `List<GroupMember> lstgroupmember = [Select UserOrGroupId, Group.Type, GroupId From GroupMember g where Group.type = 'Regular' AND UserOrGroupId='YourUserID' LIMIT 1];
if(lstgroupmember.size()>0){
  //fun
}else{
  // keep quiet
}` use this query